# Biber+biblatex+beamer undesired automatic unicode conversion

Tags: beamer, biblatex, unicode, biber

Biber is driving me crazy, converting LaTeX-encoded characters in bibliography into utf-8, which LaTeX seems to hate despite utf8 inputenc. I tried using newunicodechar, as suggested in another post, to beat the characters into LaTeX thick head, but entirely without success. Still same old complaints.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:?\global not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Is there a way to just tell biber to try to be less smart, and just pass the LaTeX-encoded characters through as is?

One of the offending entries:

```
@article {kantorovich1957rubinstein,
  AUTHOR =   {Kantorovi{\v{c}}, Leonid V. and Rubin{\v{s}}te{\u\i}n, Gennadi {\v{S}}.},
  TITLE =    {On a functional space and certain extremum problems},
  JOURNAL =  {Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR},
  VOLUME =   115,
  YEAR =     1957,
  PAGES =    {1058--1061},
}
```

Gets converted into

```
        \entry{kantorovich1957rubinstein}{article}{}
      \name{labelname}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=0943a1742c82fb1b70078279b7d4662d}{Kantorovič}{K\bibinitperiod}
{Leonid\bibnamedelima V.}{L\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim V\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=570d46535e72488202809bb8efdbf01f}{Rubinšte{\uı}n}{R\bibinitper
iod}{Gennadi\bibnamedelima Š.}{G\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim Š\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=0943a1742c82fb1b70078279b7d4662d}{Kantorovič}{K\bibinitperiod}
{Leonid\bibnamedelima V.}{L\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim V\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=570d46535e72488202809bb8efdbf01f}{Rubinšte{\uı}n}{R\bibinitper
iod}{Gennadi\bibnamedelima Š.}{G\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim Š\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{2876da645d015a8b8d125b2050486d04}
      \strng{fullhash}{2876da645d015a8b8d125b2050486d04}
      \field{sortinit}{0}
      \field{labelyear}{1957}
      \field{datelabelsource}{}
      \field{labeltitle}{On a functional space and certain extremum problems}
      \field{journaltitle}{Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR}
      \field{title}{On a functional space and certain extremum problems}
      \field{volume}{115}
      \field{year}{1957}
      \field{pages}{1058\bibrangedash 1061}
    \endentry
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out, and how to do it with latexmk. Put

```
$biber = 'biber --bblsafechars %O %B';
```

in ~/.latexmkrc.