# Biblatex. Two references under same name. When I changed the name I receive a character error

Tags: biblatex, citing

In my .bib file I have two references under the same reference name (not the authors' name. I guess there should be a professional term for the reference name). When I call that name out of the .bib file I receive an error where `\printbibliography` is located. The two references are:

```
@article{lopez2011cavitation,
    title={Cavitation in elastomeric solids: I—A defect-growth theory},
    author={Lopez-Pamies, Oscar and Idiart, Martin I and Nakamura, Toshio},
    journal={Journal of the Mechanics and Physics of Solids},
    volume={59},
    number={8},
    pages={1464--1487},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{lopez2011cavitation,
    title={Cavitation in elastomeric solids: II—Onset-of-cavitation surfaces for Neo-Hookean materials},
    author={Lopez-Pamies, Oscar and Nakamura, Toshio and Idiart, Mart{\'\i}n I},
    journal={Journal of the Mechanics and Physics of Solids},
    volume={59},
    number={8},
    pages={1488--1505},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

How can I cite these two references that can be differentialble in the text. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TexStackExc.bib}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \cite{alopez2011cavitation}
        \item \cite{blopez2011cavitation}
    \end{enumerate} 
    \newpage
    \printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

And the content of `TexStackExc.bib` is

```
@article{alopez2011cavitation,
    title={Cavitation in elastomeric solids: I—A defect-growth theory},
    author={Lopez-Pamies, Oscar and Idiart, Martin I and Nakamura, Toshio},
    journal={Journal of the Mechanics and Physics of Solids},
    volume={59},
    number={8},
    pages={1464--1487},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{blopez2011cavitation,
    title={Cavitation in elastomeric solids: II—Onset-of-cavitation surfaces for Neo-Hookean materials},
    author={Lopez-Pamies, Oscar and Nakamura, Toshio and Idiart, Martin I},
    journal={Journal of the Mechanics and Physics of Solids},
    volume={59},
    number={8},
    pages={1488--1505},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

**Answer as an edit**

The source of error was the author name, `Mart{\'\i}n`. I replaced `{\'\i}` with `i` and also deleted the temporary files and now it prints the bibliography with no error.

Comment: You can't use the same key for two bib entries, change one of them.

Comment: I did. Then I receive this error at `\printbibliography`. 

'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.

Plus I cannot cite any other key after these two in `.bib` file.

Comment: Didi you rerun biber after changing one of the keys?

Comment: It would help you would mentioned which error you get. A complete example would be a good idea too.

Comment: If I should guess: replace the `\'\i` with `í` in the bib-file.

Comment: The dash in `I—A` and `II—Onset` could also be problematic if your settings are not right. But Ulrike's guess about í is good.

Comment: I actually removed `\'\i` as well as the dash. But seems the problem is the keys. Because with the original names it well typesetes everything. Without printing the bibliography I receive no error.

Comment: The actual, underlying problem is very, very unlikely to be the key names. What you describe seems to suggest that the entries contain a character that is bad, and that character is only printed in the bibliography. If you removed the characters you need to delete the temporary files before you recompile.

Comment: All the evidence points to the `í` being problematic here. I can compile your second MWE without a problem, but if I add in `Mart{\'\i}n` again, I get the error `Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)`

Comment: @moewe That is absolutely correct. Following your comment, I had to remove the temporary files. Now I proceed with no error. Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write an answer, or do we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864?

Comment: If you use a key twice biber will complete ignore the second entry, so errors in this entry will not be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a key twice (lopez2011cavitation in your example) biber will ignore the second entry. It writes a warning about this in the .blg-file:

```
  [252] Utils.pm:169> WARN - Duplicate entry key: 'lopez2011cavitation' in file 'test.bib', skipping ...
```

This means that errors in this entry are not visible.

When you change the key names to avoid the duplicate the second entry is used too and the  `\'\i` leads to an known error, see e.g. [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864), or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268579/2388 (they are more similar questions).